# Enable Payment gateway if ACF checkbox in user profile is checked

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have added a way to enable the Woocommerce COD (cash on delivery) payment gateway for a user role of "account holder".

```
/**
* Enable COD
*/
function cod_enable_manager( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 
!current_user_can('account_holder') ) {
unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
} 
return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'cod_enable_manager' );
```

Instead I would like to enable this payment gateway if an ACF (advanced custom fields pro) checkbox in their user profile is checked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution

```
/*
 * Enable COD for account holder
 */
function enable_cod_payment( $available_gateways ) {

  global $woocommerce;
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_status = get_field('account_holder', $user );

  if ($user_status == 'Yes')  {
    $available_gateways['cod'];
    unset( $available_gateways['authorize_net_cim_credit_card'] );
  }
  else {
    unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
  }

  return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'enable_cod_payment' );
```